# Importing files into Tasty Pie WebService

Tags: python, django, web-services, tastypie

I have a webservice in tasty pie which recieves an image and saves it in a directory.Now I need to call functions present in Myfile.py,passing image as a parameter for further processing. How can I do that that?  I have tried importing MyFile.py into api.py file present in the webservice, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singnals.

Steps to follow:

1. create a `signals.py` in the same directory u have ur model for image saving
2. in the `init.py` in ur folder type this line at starting `import signals`
3. now in your signals.py

> ```
>  from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
>  from django.dispatch  import receiver
> ```

```
 @receiver(post_save, sender=YourimageModel)
 def YourFunctiononimage(sender, **kwargs)
```

: